# Archiving of Camunda BPM Process Instances

Tags: camunda

What is the best possible approach to archive the Camunda Process instances ?
 Is there a recommended setup to move or separate the historic processes from running processes.

Regards,

Phani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camunda already separates runtime information (act_ru_* tables) and historic information (act_hi_* tables).
If you would set your history level to "none", no historic information will be written at all, which shows that the engine works without historic tables.

So it is completely up to you, you can delete/archive/move historic information at will.

Typically, you would want to keep the historic information of running and recently finished instances for error analysis, and the management will be interested in historic reports, so there is more to it in deed.

What we do:

1. archive all historic information of finished processes that have been finished for at least a month.
2. provide relevant reporting data on a daily basis, so reporting is not done on the act_hi_ tables but a different, custom, schema

hope that helps.

Comment: As this answer is quite outdated but just received an upvote: The modern day solution is defining a history time to live per process model, which leads to camunda removing "old" data from the table. If you want to keep data, using a custom audit/report is still advised. Also have a look at camunda optimize which is a reporting solution directly provided by camunda for this reason.